# Precisly convert float 32 to unsigned short or unsigned char

Tags: c, casting, char, unsigned, short

First of all sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find any subject answering my question.

I'm coding a little program that will be used to convert 32-bit floating point values to short int (16 bits) and unsigned char (8 bits) values. This is for HDR images purpose.

From [here](http://lol.zoy.org/blog/2011/3/20/understanding-fast-float-integer-conversions) I could get the following function (without clamping):

```
static inline uint8_t u8fromfloat(float x)
{
    return (int)(x * 255.0f);
}
```

I suppose that in the same way we could get short int by multiplying by `(pow( 2,16 ) -1)`

But then I ended up thinking about ordered dithering and especially to Bayer dithering. To convert to uint8_t I suppose I could use a 4x4 matrix and a 8x8 matrix for unsigned short.

I also thought of a Look-up table to speed-up the process, this way:

```
uint16_t LUT[0x10000] // 2¹⁶ values contained
```

and store 2^16 unsigned short values corresponding to a float.
This same table could be then used for uint8_t as well because of the implicit cast between unsigned short ↔ unsigned int

But wouldn't a look-up table like this be huge in memory? Also how would one fill a table like this?!

Now I'm confused, what would be best according to you?

EDIT after uwind answer: Let's say now that I also want to do basic color space conversion at the same time, that is before converting to U8/U16 , do a color space conversion (in float), and then shrink it to U8/U16. Wouldn't in that case use a LUT be more efficient? And yeah I would still have the problem to index the LUT.

Comment: I've assumed this is a C question.

Comment: yes, I forgot to precise that, it is C/ C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, the look-up table won't help since in order to index into it, you need to convert the float into some integer type. Catch 22.

The table would require 0x10000 * sizeof (uint16_t) bytes, which is 128 KB. Not a lot by modern standards, but on the other hand cache is precious. But, as I said, the table doesn't add much to the solution since you need to convert float to integer in order to index.

You could do a table indexed by the raw bits of the float re-interpreted as integer, but that would have to be 32 bits which becomes very large (8 GB or so).

Go for the straight-forward runtime conversion you outlined.

Comment: Thanks unwind for your input . Let's say now that I also want to do basic color space conversion at the same time, that is before converting to U8/U16 , do a color space conversion (in float), and then shrink it to U8/U16. Wouldn't in that case use a lut be more efficient? And yeah I would still have the problem to index the lut...

Answer (score 0):

Just stay with the multiplication - it'll work fine.

Practically all modern CPU have vector instructions (SSE, AVX, ...) adapted to this stuff, so you might look at programming for that. Or use a compiler that automatically vectorizes your code, if possible (Intel C, also GCC). Even in cases where table-lookup is a possible solution, this can often be faster because you don't suffer from memory latency.

Answer (score 0):

First, it should be noted that `float` has 24 bits of precision, which can no way fit into a 16-bit `int` or even 8 bits. Second, float have much larger range, which can't be stored in any `int` or `long long int`

So your question title is actually **incorrect**, no way to precisely convert any float to short or char. You want to ***map*** a float value between 0 and 1 to an 8-bit or 16-bit int range.

---

For the code you use above, it'll work fine. However **the value 255 is extremely unlikely to be returned** because it needs **exactly 1.0 as input**, otherwise values such as 254.99999 will ended up being truncated as 254. You should round the value instead

```
return (int)(x * 255.0f + .5f);
```

or better, use the code provided in your link for more **balanced distribution**

```
static inline uint8_t u8fromfloat_trick(float x)
{
    union { float f; uint32_t i; } u;
    u.f = 32768.0f + x * (255.0f / 256.0f);
    return (uint8_t)u.i;
}
```

Using LUT wouldn't be any faster because **a table for 16-bit values is too large for fitting in cache**, and in fact may reduce your performance greatly. The snippet above needs only 2 floating-point instructions, or only 1 with [FMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set). And SIMD will improve performance 4-32x (or more) further, so LUT method would be easily outperformed as it's much harder to parallelize table look ups